# How can there be no users with the IP address of a user?

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

Looking into a possible problem user on [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour), today I opened the user's profile and tried to see what *other* users had been using the same IP address,

[image]

but what I got was rather surprising:

[image]

Normally you see *at least* the user in whose profile you found the IP address you started from.

The original user *is* registered and has visited the site recently. The situation persisted despite reloading.

Is this a known behavior?

Comment: Maybe the users with ip xx.xx.xx.xx list is cached or something.

Comment: @Tim I don't see why it would have been generated *before* a user was found from there for there to be a cached empty version.

Comment: Yeah but it could be a key value store or something and the key didn't exist. Doesn't matter I am guessing. probably wrong

Comment: Maybe his IP is changing every minute and by the time you opened the list, his IP changed already?

Comment: @ShadowWizard The IP listed in the profile has remained the same.